# When Model popup opens by default .modal-backdrop is applying and monitor screen get disable

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am using Angular js. The issue is when bootstrap model open by default `.modal-backdrop` class is applying and because of this whole screen get dim and not enable. please suggest me something.

```
$(".modal-backdrop").fadeOut()
$("#formId").removeClass('.modal-backdrop')
```

Comment: `I'm using angularjs...` Please then do not tag with `angular`. Also removed asp net tag, since this has nothing to do with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

By design a modal is supposed to overtake control of the screen, hence the backdrop.

That being said, you can display the modal without the backdrop.

```
$("#myModal2").modal({backdrop: false});
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/#options

Angular has configuration as well

```
config.backdrop = false;
```

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#config

Here is a stackblitz example with backdrop disabled

https://stackblitz.com/angular/aqvnlngdjon